# Convert decimal to float with ijson.items

Tags: python, ijson

I am reading a big array of JSONS from a file with `ijson.items` , but numbers are converted to type Decimal.

Example `Decimal('14.2')`

The [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/ijson/) says that there is an option `use-float = true`. But I don't know where to put this option.

Is it possible to use `ijson.items`and obtain floats?

Comment: please, show your code

Answer (score 6):

```py
ijson.items(file, 'your.prefix', use_float=True)
```

Comment: It does not work: `TypeError: items() missing 1 required positional argument: 'prefix'`

Comment: Updated, I don't know what prefix you use there, an empty string for the root

Comment: this works like a charm